# For any $ r \gt 0$ let $M=\lbrace z\in \mathbb C; |z| = 1 , |z - 3i| = r\rbrace$ and $A = \lbrace r \gt 0; |M| = 1 \rbrace$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

For any $ r \gt 0$ let $M=\lbrace z\in \mathbb C; |z| = 1 , |z - 3i| = r\rbrace$ and $A = \lbrace r \gt 0; |M| = 1 \rbrace$.
Find the sum of the elements of $A$.

I tried to understand what I need to find. Here is what I thought:
$M$ is the set of the complex numbers that satisfy those two equalities. So any number $z = a + ib$ it needs to satisfy:
$(1) \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = 1$
$(2) \sqrt{a^2+ (b-3)^2} =r, \, r\gt 0$

Then $A$ is the set of the complex number for which the set $M$ contains just a number.

Did I get this right so far? Next I tried to find $a$ and $b$ by solving $(1)$ and $(2)$. I substituted $a^2 = 1 - b^2$ in the second equation and got:
$\sqrt{10-6b} = r, \, r\gt 0$

Now I have no clue what to do or even if I am on the right path. Help me a bit, please.

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct. With your method, you now just need to express $b$ in terms of $r$ and then $a$ in terms of $r$. Note that when you would try to do the second part, you will get two solutions for $a$ in general, with opposite signs. Now how do you ensure there is only one solution of $a$ instead of two? Also as the answer suggests, it might be easier to do this geometrically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The Cartesian equation of $|z|=1$ is $x^2+y^2=1$. The Cartesian equation of $|z-3i|=r$ is $x^2+(y-3)^2=r^2$. Draw a sketch of these two circles. Notice there are only two possible values of $r$ that ensure the circles intersect in a single point. Can you see what they are?

Comment: I was not aware there is such a thing as equation for circles, I just googled it. I will now try to draw them.

Comment: Equivalently, if it's any easier to draw, $|z|=1$ are the complex numbers $z$ a distance 1 from the origin and $|z-3i|=r$ are the complex numbers $z$ a distance $r$ from 3i in the complex plane.